# Using OpenID Connect Authentification in ASP MVS .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, openid

I have a problem; I use on my localhost the following code in Startup.cs

> ConfigureServices

Method. Without

```
oauthOptions.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
```

I cannot Redirect, but my problem is that the user cannot authenticate. Can someone help me?

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultForbidScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(oauthOptions =>
        {
            oauthOptions.ClientId = "b6514a30-c3dc-0136-0d4f-0685c268206c137310";
            oauthOptions.ClientSecret = "secret here";
            oauthOptions.Authority = "https://test.onelogin.com/oidc";
            oauthOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            oauthOptions.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            oauthOptions.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://ed40a182.ngrok.io/home/index";

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };

            oauthOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role,
                ValidateIssuer = true
            };

            oauthOptions.SaveTokens = true;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        ;
```